# Filter on column with TRUE or FALSE values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im quite new to google script but this is boggling me and I thought I would have some quick fix from someone ?

I am trying to filter on a column (E) having TRUE or FALSE values. I thought I could access that column with item[4] but it seems to get my row instead of my column .... I dont get it because I used to get my column with this item[i] before.... here is my code below. All help would be greatly appreciated

```
function hiddenrowssummary() {

  ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var summary=ss.getSheetByName('Summary');

  var originaldata=summary.getRange(1,1,summary.getLastRow()-1,summary.getLastColumn()).getValues();


  var filtervalues= originaldata.filter(filterlogic);

  Logger.log(filtervalues);


}




var filterlogic= function(item){

     return item[4]==="TRUE";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

[*Boolean type vs String type Strict equality comparison*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

#### Solution:

Use the same type on both sides of the comparison operator.

If the item type is boolean in spreadsheet, use `true`:

```
 return item[4] === true;
```

If the item type is string in spreadsheet, then you should use

```
 return item[4] === 'TRUE';
```

You can check the type of a value in spreadsheet using [`=TYPE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375)

Comment: Hi @TheMaster thank you for that response. But I still get nothing....my column with the TRUE or FALSE string is located in column E (so [4])....and if I understand correctly with item[4][0] you are accessing only one cell: row 5 column 1.....

Comment: I want to access all the TRUE / FALSE values from column 5 and depending on the TRUE or FALSE value, filter on that

Comment: @dany Sorry about that. Check now. Just try `true` without `[0]`

Comment: This is exactly what I tried....and it gets me no result. But I have done a similar thing last week and it worked so I really don't get it.

Comment: Also, when I `Logger.log(originaldata[4]);` it gives me the values of the row number 5 and not the values of the column number 5 ....

Comment: @dany orginaldata[4] is row5 and orginaldata[4][4] is row 5 col 5. `.filter` iterates through all rows, so item will be each row and item[4] will be each row's col 5. Regardless, `This is exactly what I tried` Did you try without quotes and lowercase, like I've put above?

Comment: My god ! it works.....I thought I was going crazy. Thank you so much @TheMaster ...it was indeed item[4]===true; ....

Comment: But Thank you :)

Comment: @dany It's not string. It's usually boolean, espescially with all caps.  try `=type(E5)` if it returns 4, it's boolean. If that answers your question, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: it does type 4. Thanks for the tip :)